# JS Closure - Multiple date picker initializations / invocations that relies on callback

Tags: javascript, closures

How do I properly invoke and initialize multiple datepickers (Bootstrap date picker) on the following script using a closure so that I will not have to duplicate my functions for each date picker id?

http://www.daterangepicker.com/ is the picker I am using

cb_helper <---- This is where I tried to use a closure unsuccessfully so that I will "remember" the id passed in...

What am I doing wrong?

**JS**

```
 $(function() {
     var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
     var end = moment();
     var idVal = "";
    function cb(start, end) {
        $(idVal + ' span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }



    function cb_helper(id, start, end)
    {
      (function(){
          idVal = id;
          cb(start, end);
      })();
    }

    function init(id){
      $(id).daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
      }, cb);
    }

    init("#reportrange_profitability");
    init("#reportrange_volume");
    cb_helper("#reportrange_profitability", start, end);
    cb_helper("#reportrange_volume", start, end);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();


    function cb(idVal) {
        return function(start, end) {
            $(idVal + ' span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        }
    }


    function init(id, start, end) {
        $(id).daterangepicker({
            startDate: start,
            endDate: end,
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            }
        }, cb(id));
    }

    init("#reportrange_profitability", start, end);
    init("#reportrange_volume", start, end);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying to return a function from the enclosing cb function just as you responded.